# Matlab: Using imagesc in grayscale without black

Tags: matlab, colors, grayscale

Beginning with a simple 2D matrix m of either 0 or 1 as an example:

```
m = [ 0 0 0 1 1
      0 1 1 1 0
      1 1 0 0 1
      0 0 0 1 0 ]
```

How would I get this image to be displayed in a figure as only white and one gray using imagesc()? Currently, my code would is something like this:

```
imagesc(m)
colormap(gray)
colorbar
```

I've experimented with various ways to adjust the colormap and set limits on which values are used with CLim, but I have not found a way to limit the actual colors themselves so that instead of having white and black for values of 0 and 1, we have a white and (light) gray value for 1 and 0, respectively. Any quick and easy ways to do this?

Note: I should also mention that I want these so I can overlay a a contour plot of the same dimensions (but different values) and by using black, so I'm not sure if that would factor into any answers, but I am also open to suggestions with that in mind.

Comment: Try this - `caxis([-1 1])` after `colorbar`

Comment: Thanks @Divakar, that is incredibly simple. Sorry to ask such a novice question. Nothing I had found pointed me to caxis. :-\

Comment: Glad it worked for you, I think that was just a hack I suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
imagesc(m)
cmap = [.7 .7 .7 %// light gray
        1  1  1] %// white
colormap(cmap)
colorbar('Ytick',[.25 .75],'Yticklabel',[0 1]) %// only two values in colorbar
```

[image]